# Spring Form Tag - Security Issue

Tags: hibernate, security, spring-mvc

I'm not quite sure about using Spring MVC form tag with Hibernate:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

Because if you have a table with the following structure:

```
create table person (
    phone_number varchar(20),
    country_id int
)
```

Then hibernate will map it to a class like this:

```
public class Person (
    String phoneNumber;
    Integer countryId;

    // setters and getters
)
```

And in the spring jsp form we have:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="controller_path" modelAttribute="person">
    <form:input type="text" path="phoneNumber"/>
    <form:input type="text" path="countryId"/>
</form:form>
```

Which will generate the following html:

```
<form method="POST" action="controller_path">
    <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber">
    <input type="text" id="countryId" name="countryId">
</form>
```

Isn't that insecure that the generated html shows exactly the fields names of the class Person, because eventually I think someone can guess the table's column names?

Is there a way to prevent this? Or is not something to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the complete MVC setup of Spring and use hibernate/JPA/another ORM with checks the content of the parameters for you (effectively escaping the data in strings/text objects), and if in cases where you insert the data yourself you use parametrized statements, it should be ok.

There is a huge contradiction tough in coding advice:

1) *Do not show parameter names equal to what you use in your database*

2) and REST: *Have objects with the same names as your column definitions*.

Since a human like some recognizable column names when querying the database later on, the second advice seems to be used way more.

(my) Conclusion: Assuming you use parametrized statements, and you check ownership of the objects you are updating, it should not pose a problem.